# How to know boot time on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, logs

How to get via terminal log of system boot time for last month.
I tried to use last boot command, bit it returned information from the beginning of month.

Comment: By "boot time" you mean a list of boots in last month? What init system are you using?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/51771/how-to-measure-boot-time

Answer (score 8):

I know Ubuntu has systemd now, but I haven't tested this out on Ubuntu. If you have systemd then the following command should work.

```
systemd-analyze
```

If you are trying to increase boot performance then you might want to look at the output of

```
systemd-analyze blame
```

For more info see the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improve_boot_performance)

Answer (score 6):

last boot

```
who -b
```

lasts boot (no pun intend)

```
last boot
```

- this will list boots from 1st to today

Comment: In many systems, the user is called reboot instead (as in `last reboot`).

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu the file `/var/log/wtmp` (`last` gets data from this file by default) is rotated by `logrotate` following this configuration :

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    rotate 1
}
```

As you can see it will be rotated monthly, with only one rotational file will exist meaning `/var/log/wtmp` will contain current month's logs while `/var/log/wtmp.1` will contain previous month's logs. No logs prior to that will be saved. you can change this configuration to suite your need if you want.

Now while you run `last` command you will see current month's logs as the file `/var/log/wtmp` is read by `last` by default. As we know that the previous month's logs are saved in `/var/log/wtmp.1`, we can tell `last` to read from that file using `-f` option :

```
last -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```

Same goes for the `/var/log/btmp` file while using `lastb`.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative to retrieve the *system boot date* consist using **vmstat(8)** in statistics mode with *--stats* argument.

The command expose the following line:

```
...
TIMESTAMP boot time
...
```

So the line can be parsed with **gawk(1)** and the timestamp can be converted using the **date(1)** command to a human readable format with the command below:

```
  $ TIMESTAMP=$(vmstat --stats | awk '/boot time/{print $1}')
  $ date -d @$TIMESTAMP
  or
  $ date -d @$(vmstat --stats | awk '/boot time/{print $1}')
```

And another alternative, by using **dmesg(1)** with the *-T* argument to render the timestamp in human readable format and search for the *Command Line* pattern.

The *Command Line* pattern line indicate the Kernel boot command line and the timestamp in the kernel ring buffer which gives the system boot time:

```
$ dmesg -T|grep -i 'Command line'|head -1
```

These approachs will work on every Linux systems, not only Ubuntu distribution. Finally, the best portable way is using `who -b` has mentioned previously because it's portable across systems such as Linux, Unix, OSX and FreeBSD.

Answer (score 0):

The `uptime` command normally shows the relative uptime (and much more), but it has a handy `-s|--since` command-line flag that uses a standard `yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` format:

```
$ uptime -s
2023-10-23 07:16:53
```

Unlike the other answers, no parsing / output processing is required, and `uptime` itself is pretty standard, too.